# ModelMultipleChoiceField CheckboxSelectMultiple Select a valid choice. That choice is not one of the available choices

Tags: python, django, forms

So the problem is that when I try to post data on the server.
The form correctly lists checkboxes. However, when I select something and then submit the form, I'll get the form error:

```
Select a valid choice. That choice is not one of the available choices
```

forms.py

```
class addGoods(forms.Form):
   ...

    loading_type = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Loading_type.objects.all(), widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple, empty_label=None)

   ...
```

models.py

```
class Add_good(models.Model):
   ...

    loading_type = models.ManyToManyField(Loading_type, related_name="+")

   ...
```

I read that i should override the `__init__` in forms, but I'm new at Django, that's why need your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that your field does not match the widget. You are using a `ModelChoiceField` (for choosing one choice) with `CheckboxSelectMultiple` widget (for choosing multiple choices).

Since you have a many-to-many field in your models, you want a [`ModelMultipleChoiceField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField) instead.

```
class addGoods(forms.Form):
    ...

    loading_type = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Loading_type.objects.all(), widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple, empty_label=None)
```